# When inside of a Parsley form event handler, possible to refresh all fields?

Tags: parsley.js

inside of

```
$('form').parsley().on('form:validate', parsleyForm => {
    // I want to parsleyForm.reset() to clear all error messages on fields
})
```

Is there is a method which currently does this?

Comment: Would you care explaining why you'd do that? If there's an error message, it's because those fields are invalid. Validating a form does not normally remove error messages, it only adds them... Field (should) automatically remove errors as soon as the data becomes valid.

Comment: I have some logic in the handler which conditionally validates only certain form fields, so i want to clear the messages on the other fields.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just call this:

```
$('form').parsley().reset();
```

http://parsleyjs.org/doc/#psly-usage-form  <= In the Methods section.

Comment: True, but I don't know what that would do when called from inside `form:validate` event!

Comment: Well hopefully if this doesn't work for the OP, they will let us know.

Comment: Not sure why but it doesn't work for me.  I did `parsleyForm.$element.parsley().reset()` and also did `$('form').parsley().reset()` but neither cleared the error messages in question.  I should add that the source of the error messages i'm trying to clear is a custom remote validator which manually adds the error messages via `this.addError`.  Does this place the error message outside of the scope of what Parsley has knowledge of?

Comment: I should also add that the `input` in question is hidden, and so the errors are being displayed in an `errors-container`.  This shouldn't make a difference though.